# How to control global Web Audio volume without specific AudioContext reference?

Tags: javascript, audio, html5-audio, web-audio-api

Recently my boss ask me to fix bugs in our old website projects. Problem happened when I tried to silence website media when the website is hidden.
The old project used Howler.js as its audio player. This lib seem used the Web Audio APIs to handle music sources, so that there is no audio element can be handled. What's worse is that some old projects' source code is lost, so I cannot use Howler reference to control the global volume either.

So I want to find out if there is a way to control global Web Audio volume without specific AudioContext reference? Or at least find the audio context created inside the website?

Comment: `some old projects' source code is lost` makes it hard to make ANY changes, since rebuilding without the lost source code is likely to break things - I am assuming that there is a "build" step for the website of course

Comment: does [documentation](https://github.com/goldfire/howler.js#volumevolume) help

Comment: @JaromandaX To change the Howler volume a global reference of Howler obj is needed. Some of the projects dose have a global Howler reference. I have already handled it. But still some projects don't have the reference. That makes me confused.

Comment: How is Howler being loaded? a script tag? a `require`? an `import`?

Comment: @JaromandaX Imported as a module

Comment: @JaromandaX I find that an audio element created by code whitch is hidden from document can also play a music. """var audio = document.createElement('audio'); audio.src = './music.mp3'; audio.play(); document.querySelector('audio'); // undefined""" :(

Comment: then can't you just add code that `import {Howler} from 'howler'; Howler.volume(0.5);` or whatever

Comment: @JaromandaX I added this code already. I don't know if it can work or not. We will publish the patch to website at next weeken. Hope it can work. Thank you for your answer.